# Is it possible to configure wsHttpBinding for authentication only (Kerberos token), no signing/encryption

Tags: vb.net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, ws-security

I have a web service running outside of .net that I need to invoke from a .NET client.

I was given a .NET client written in Visual Basic to test with.

The .NET client can access the web service with a clear-text SOAP message using `basicHttpBinding`.

I can configure a policy/binding for the external web service to use the Kerberos token for Message Level Protection and authentication.  I can access this web service from the .NET client by modifying the configuration file to use `wsHttpBinding`.

Now, the requirement is to use the Kerberos token for authentication only and not sign/encrypt the SOAP message.  That is, I only need the  tags in the SOAP header.  I have this configuration working on the external web service, but now I want to modify the configuration file so the .NET client only sends the  and does not sign/encrypt any part of the SOAP message.

Is it possible to modify the .net client's .config file to do this?

My understanding is that `basicHttpBinding` can not be modified to use a Kerberos token (only UserName/Certificate).

I've tried disabling signing/encryption in `wsHttpBinding` via an attribute such as "defaultProtectionLevel=Sign/SignEncrypt/None", but this isn't available in `wsHttpBinding` (or I can't find it).  I can only disable or enable message level protection and authentication with .

I've also tried building a `customBinding`, but can not disable signing/encryption and use the Kerberos token for authentication only.

Does anyone have a solution or some tips that could point me in the right direction to go about solving the above issues?

Comment: Yes, use Java. Really, it's lot easier and out of the box.